# Sencha tab bar bottom in google chrome browser iphone does't appear

Tags: iphone, extjs, touch, tabbar

I'm new to sencha, I'm starting with a web app for ios and android but this example [Kitchen Sink](http://cdn.sencha.io/touch/sencha-touch-2.1.0/examples/kitchensink/index.html#demo/icons) the tab bar bottom in google chrome browser iphone does not appear totally, anyone know why?